# How to read a space separated file, with some needed, misformatted rows, into pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, csv

I changed a CSV file and copied everything into Excel file.

I'm trying to split a list in one column into 2 more columns.

Here is my code that Copy from CVS file into new Excel file:

```py
read_file = pd.read_csv('new_names.csv', sep='\t')

read_file.to_excel('Setup_Loss.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

The thing is that I want to split each number into a different column.

Here is my result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Given the following space separated data in a file called `test.csv`

  - [image]
- The first two rows do not look correctly formatted, so they will be skipped by using `skiprows=[0, 1]`.
- Two of the columns are both named `'Formatted Data'`, so pandas appends `'.1'` to the repeated column name.

  - Use `df = df.rename(columns={'Formatted Data': 'some name', 'Formatted Data.1': 'some other name'})` to rename the columns.
- If `sep=' '` doesn't work, try `sep='\\s+'`

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the data in and skip the first 2 rows
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=[0, 1], sep=' ')

# display(df)
   Frequency  Formatted Data  Formatted Data.1
0        3.0             2.1               0.0
1        3.0             2.1               0.1
2        3.0             2.1               0.2
3        3.0             2.1               0.3
4        3.0             2.1               0.4
5        3.0             2.1               0.5
6        3.0             2.1               0.6

# save to Excel
df.to_excel('Setup_Loss.xlsx', index=None, header=True)
```

### Alternatively

- If the information in row 1 and 2 needs to be in the new file
- The file can be read in with `open`, clean the rows, and then add them to a dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file in to clean the headers, and split the data
with open('test.csv') as f:
    rows = list(f.readlines())
    
    # select the header rows and clean them
    h1 = rows[0].strip().split('# ')[1]
    h2 = rows[1].strip().split('# ')[1]
    h3 = [v.replace('"', '') for v in rows[2].strip().split(' "')]
    
    # select and split the data
    data = [r.strip().split(' ') for r in rows[3:]]

# create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=h3)

# add h1 and h2 as multi-level headers
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[h1], [h2], df.columns])

# save to Excel
# in order to save multi-level headers to Excel, the index must be True
df.to_excel('Setup_Loss.xlsx', header=True)

# alternatively, save as a csv
df.to_csv('updated_test.csv', index=False)

# display(df)
                                Channel 1                              
                                  Trace 1                              
  Frequency Formatted Data Formatted Data
0       3.0            2.1            0.0
1       3.0            2.1            0.1
2       3.0            2.1            0.2
3       3.0            2.1            0.3
4       3.0            2.1            0.4
5       3.0            2.1            0.5
6       3.0            2.1            0.6
```

### `test.csv`

```py
# Channel 1
# Trace 1
Frequency "Formatted Data" "Formatted Data"
3.0 2.1 0.0
3.0 2.1 0.1
3.0 2.1 0.2
3.0 2.1 0.3
3.0 2.1 0.4
3.0 2.1 0.5
3.0 2.1 0.6
```